# How can I draw this Venn-like diagram using rectangles in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been looking into TikZ figures and can somewhat adapt them.
To create one that has the capabilities that I would like is another matter.

For my thesis I am looking to create this figure[image: Company overview]

I know it is a simple one but I am struggling with the alignment

So i have been fiddling a bit the result is not bad, but id like to line out the green boxes

This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} [
        title/.style={font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{black!45}},
        capt/.style={font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{black!45},node distance=10em,anchor=west},
        firm/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!23, rounded corners, minimum width=6em,fill opacity=0.5},
        industry/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!23, rounded corners, minimum width=25em,fill opacity=0.3},
        region/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=red!23, rounded corners, minimum height=2em,fill opacity=0.3},
        ]
        % Place nodes
        \node (dummy) {};
        \node [title] (in)[right=2cm of dummy] {India};
        \node [title] [below=5mm of in] (infy) {Infosys};

        \node [title] (wp) [below=1.5cm of in]  {WiPro};
        \node [firm] (InIt) [draw=black!50, fit= (infy) (wp)] {};



        \node [title] (eur) [right=2cm of in] {Europa};        
        \node [title] (cap) [below=5mm of eur] {Cap};
        \node [title] (Ts)  [below=1.5cm of eur] {Tsystems};
        \node [firm] (EuIt) [draw=black!50, fit= (cap) (Ts)] {};



        \node [capt] (its) [below=1.25cm of dummy] {IT Services};
        \node [capt] (ph) [below=3.5cm of dummy] {Pharmaceutical};

        \node [industry][draw=black!50, fit=(its)(InIt)(EuIt)]{}; 
        \node [title] (ran) [below=3cm of in]  {Ranbaxy};
        \node [title] (cip) [below=4cm of in]  {Cipla};
        %\node [draw=black!50, fit=(ph)(wp)(cap)]{}; 

        \node [title] (nov) [below=3cm of eur]  {Novartis};
        \node [title] (gsk) [below=4cm of eur]  {GSK};
        \node [firm] (EuPh) [draw=black!50, fit= (nov) (gsk)]  {};
        \node [firm] (InPh) [draw=black!50, fit= (ran) (cip)]  {};

        \node [region] [draw=black!50, fit=(eur)(EuPh)]{}; 
        \node [region] [draw=black!50, fit=(in)(InPh)]{}; 
        \node [industry] [draw=black!50, fit=(ph)(InPh)(EuPh)]{}; 

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Clients graph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Let me know when you edited your question and I’ll redeem my downvote ;-)

Comment: I would define four nodes for the texts "Nov/GSK", "CIP/RAN", etc and use `fit` library to draw another nodes which encloses those, first horizontally, then vertically, and use `label` attributes for the enclosing ones to put the EU, IN, Pharma, and ITS labels.

Comment: @Tobi, I have provided the MWE. Thanks for responding

Comment: @wierts: Your code looks good, what is it that you're trying to add to the figure? Just the four boxes?

Comment: @KevinC I am trying to create the picture. The code does compile but i do not know how to continue from here towards the picture i have posted

Comment: +1 now :-) Just a note: I use `\tikzset` in the preamble for global settings and for local settings the optional argument of `{tikzpicture}` …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `\matrix` to position the Firm nodes, and manually draw the boxes. (Somehow the `fit` library doesn't work, and so the boxes are not drawn with the most elegant code `:(`).

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,positioning,matrix,calc} 
\usepackage{verbatim}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, top color=white, bottom color=yellow!50,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=3em, text centered},
    myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=1pt, thick},
    mylabel/.style={text width=7em, text centered}, 
    myFirm/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, thin, inner sep=1em, minimum size=3em, text centered}
}  

\matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
  nodes={myFirm},
  row sep=5ex,
  column sep=10ex,
]{
  Novatis GSK & Cipla Ranbaxy \\
  Cap T-sys & Infy WP \\
};

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\thinpad{3pt}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\thickpad{6pt}
\draw let \p{11nw}=(m-1-1.north west), \p{11se}=(m-1-1.south east), 
          \p{21nw}=(m-2-1.north west), \p{21se}=(m-2-1.south east),
          \p{12nw}=(m-1-2.north west), \p{12se}=(m-1-2.south east),
          \p{22se}=(m-2-2.south east) in
  ($(\x{11nw},\y{11nw})+(-\thinpad,\thickpad)$)rectangle($(\x{11se},\y{21se})+(\thinpad,-\thickpad)$)
  ($(\x{12nw},\y{12nw})+(-\thinpad,\thickpad)$)rectangle($(\x{12se},\y{22se})+(\thinpad,-\thickpad)$)
  ($(\x{11nw},\y{11nw})+(-\thickpad,\thinpad)$)rectangle($(\x{12se},\y{12se})+(\thickpad,-\thinpad)$)
  ($(\x{11nw},\y{21nw})+(-\thickpad,\thinpad)$)rectangle($(\x{12se},\y{22se})+(\thickpad,-\thinpad)$)
;

\node[mynode,above=of m-1-1]{Europe};
\node[mynode,above=of m-1-2]{India};
\node[mynode,left =2.5 of m-1-1.center](Ph){Pharma};
\node[mynode,left =2.5 of m-2-1.center]{ITS};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Update

In response to the update of OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows,backgrounds}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture} [
      title/.style={font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{black!45},align=center,on grid},
      capt/.style={font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{black!45},node distance=10em,anchor=west},
      firm/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!23, rounded corners, minimum width=6em,minimum height=3em,fill opacity=0.5},
      industry/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!23, rounded corners, minimum width=9cm,minimum height=1.5cm,on grid,fill opacity=0.3},
      region/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=red!23, rounded corners, minimum height=2em,fill opacity=0.3},
    ]
    % industry and region boxes
    \node(IT)[industry]{};
    \node(Ph)[industry,below=2cm of IT]{};

    % place coordinates for later use
    \coordinate(r1c1)at($(IT.west)!.2!(IT.east)$);
    \coordinate(r1c2)at($(IT.west)!.5!(IT.east)$);
    \coordinate(r1c3)at($(IT.west)!.85!(IT.east)$);
    \coordinate(r2c1)at($(Ph.west)!.2!(Ph.east)$);
    \coordinate(r2c2)at($(Ph.west)!.5!(Ph.east)$);
    \coordinate(r2c3)at($(Ph.west)!.85!(Ph.east)$);

    % firm boxes
    \node(f1)[firm] at(r1c2){};
    \node(f2)[firm] at(r2c2){};
    \node(f3)[firm] at(r1c3){};
    \node(f4)[firm] at(r2c3){};

    % Place nodes
    \node[title] at (r1c1){IT Services};
    \node[title] at (r2c1){Pharmaceutical};

    \node[title] at (r1c2){Infosys \\ WiPro};
    \node[title] at (r2c2){Ranbaxy \\ Cipla};

    \node[title] at (r1c3){Cap \\ Tsystems};
    \node[title] at (r2c3){Novartis \\ GSK};

    \node(IND)[title,yshift=1.2cm] at (r1c2) {India};
    \node(EUR)[title,yshift=1.2cm] at (r1c3) {Europe};

    % region boxes
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node[region,fit=(IND) (f2)]{};
      \node[region,fit=(EUR) (f4)]{};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Clients graph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: This is quite brilliant, One more question: Is is possible to have the names of the firms BELOW (and with bullets) each other. I had them side by side cos i do not know how to do this?

Comment: @wierts: you mean like an `itemize` environment?

Comment: Exactly that is what i would like

Comment: I got the fit to work. See my MWE now i just have to line out the boxes and I am golden

Comment: @wierts: I've updated my answer. You can play with the width and height parameters to get the right sizes of boxes. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: `text opacity=1`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: The OP has set text color to be `\color{black!45}`; that's what's causing the texts to appear faint.

Comment: May the force be with you! Your help has been greatly appreciated!